# Unable to connect to Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB vCore using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, pymongo

I'm trying to setup the connection for my MongoDb vCore cluster using pymongo, here is the code I have used

```
mongo_conn = "mongodb+srv://"+COSMOS_MONGO_USER+":"+COSMOS_MONGO_PWD+"@"+COSMOS_MONGO_SERVER+"?tls=true&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256&retrywrites=false&maxIdleTimeMS=120000"

mongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient(mongo_conn)
```

Following is the error I have received.

**ConfigurationError: nameserver is not a dns.nameserver.Nameserver instance or text form, IP address, nor a valid https URL**

COSMOS_MONGO_SERVER values was in this format:

sample-db.mongocluster.cosmos.azure.com/

Environment:

Python: 3.11.5

Pymongo : 4.5

Comment: Maybe test using an exact connection string vs. mixing with variables to eliminate the possibility of an error in string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to connect to Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB vCore using pymongo:

**Below are the steps I followed to connect Mongo DB using pymongo:**

- `import pymongo` allows you to use Python to interface with MongoDB databases.
- `mongo_client` establishing a connection to the MongoDB server.
- It uses `collection.find()` to retrieve all documents from the supplied collection, then iterates through the documents and prints each one to the terminal.
- If an exception occurs during execution, `except` block collects and publishes the error message.

**Below Is the code I tried:**

```py
import pymongo

cosmosMongoUser = "*****"
cosmosMongoPwd = "*****"
cosmosMongoServ = "*****"
cosmosDbName = "newDb"
cosmosCollName = "id"
mongo_conn = f"*****"

try:
    mongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient(mongo_conn)
    
    db = mongo_client[cosmosDbName]
    collection = db[cosmosCollName]
   
    documents = collection.find()
    for document in documents:
        print(document)
        
except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", str(e))
finally:
    mongo_client.close()
```

**Input:**

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64f97842d438121c2813c320"),
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "Pavan Balaji",
    "age" : 24
}
```

**Output:**
Output In Terminal:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('64f97842d438121c2813c320'), 'id': '1', 'name': 'Pavan Balaji', 'age': 24}
```

Comment: I'm also following the same approach and I still get the error message which I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: Check version of **pymongo**. Please make sure the `cosmosMongoServ` variable is properly set in your code and also `connectionString` is formatted correctly. Check the **hostname** mentioned in connection string. Verify that no firewall or network issues are preventing outgoing connections to the MongoDB server.